# Minor visual bug with the new GUI style

Tags: bug, status-completed, user-interface

There are some irregularities when the browser window is narrow, just before switching to the "narrow" layout:

[image]

Note the element overlap.

Comment: Same, and I follow a lot of tags, so the "Public questions tagged ..." takes half the screen...

Comment: What's worse is when it *doesn't* bleed and the text which is obscured by the Hot Meta Posts is the part of the code you cannot scroll to. This is more of an issue when viewing an individual question but a symptom of the same general problem.

Comment: I [can't see the problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19478/the-many-memes-of-meta/19775#19775)

Comment: @Dave `I can't see ̶t̶h̶e̶ ̶p̶r̶o̶b̶l̶e̶m̶`  ftfy

Comment: Well, wise people say "if it ain't broke don't try to fix it" but I guess they do have to do something to spend the budget in order to not get it cut next year.